# Magnetic field closed loop lines in an electromagnetic wave

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, antennas

let's consider the simplest example of electromagnetic waves:

[image]

If we consider only this picture, it seems that the magnetic field lines are not closed loops, which is clearly not possible. I know it is due to the fact that each vector in the picture is applied only in one point of space, and that to see the closed loops we probably have to consider more points on the transverse plane.

But I need a confirmation of this, and above all I do not imagine how these closed loops are. If I repeat this picture many times on the transverse plane, I do not see any closed loop. So I need help for visualizing the overall electromagnetic wave in space.

Comment: Are you asking *specifically* about a linearly polarized plane wave? Or are you asking about electromagnetic waves in general?

Comment: My doubt is general, but if it is easier to visualize the magnetic loops for a linearly polarized plane wave, it is anyway very good for me!

Comment: In the absence of charges also the E field lines need to form closed loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My doubt is general, but if it is easier to visualize the magnetic
> loops for a linearly polarized plane wave

Look at this visualization of the magnetic field lines (red) of the radiation from a center fed dipole antenna:

[image]

[Image credit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna#Hertzian_dipole)

Imagine how this looks arbitrarily far away (from an arbitrarily powerful source), where the radius of the magnetic field line loops becomes arbitrarily large and the wavefronts are arbitrarily close to being plane wavefronts.

In the limit, the magnetic field line loop radius goes to infinity so they don't close (or they 'loop around at infinity').

Thus, you won't find the magnetic field line loops you're looking for in plane waves.